# How to perform a binomial expansion on $m*v^2$?

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients, physics, binomial-theorem

I have been told by a couple of folks in passing, one of whom was a mathematician, that through binomial expansion of $m*v^2$ (where *v* is used in place of *c*), that all 5 Major Forces (Strong Force, Electromagnetism, Weak Force, Gravity, and Magnetism) can be shown.

Unfortunately I have been out of the mathematical loop for over a decade and I was hoping that someone might demonstrate how to expand something like this with some basic instructions to the process.

Comment: The expression $m v^2$ is already a simple monomial. It can't be expanded. Also, there are only 4 fundamental forces (electromagnetism and magnetism are the same thing). Something similar to this does come up in special relativity, but it isn't directly related to forces and you have the wrong general expression. The expression you gave is actually twice the classical kinetic energy of a point object. It has no essential relationship to any of the fundamental forces.

Comment: Here is a link to the wiki page about [kinetic energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy#Relativistic_kinetic_energy_of_rigid_bodies) which gives the result of a binomial expansion on the general formula

Answer (score 3):

What you have been told is utter nonsense.  I would ignore it.

Comment: Well these folks have a very high regard in my mind as they are both talented folks. I'll ask them for the writeup and post it here.

Answer (score 1):

The "$m$" you've been told about is the so-called **relativistic mass**. Usually, when physicists talk about mass they're actually talking about $m_o$ the **rest mass**. In contrast, the "$m$" your acquaintances have mentioned is captured by
$$ m(v) = \frac{m_o}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}} $$
where $c$ is the speed of light in vacuo and $v$ is the speed at which the particle in question travels. Often the ratio $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$ is called $\gamma$ and sometimes $\beta = v/c$ hence $\gamma = (1-\beta^2)^{-1/2}$. Apply the binomial series to obtain:
$$ \gamma = 1-\frac{1}{2}\beta^2+ \cdots $$
multiply by $m_oc^2$ to obtain: note $c^2\beta^2=v^2$ hence,
$$ mc^2 = m_o\gamma c^2 = m_oc^2+ \frac{1}{2}mv^2 + \cdots $$
The first term is the **rest-energy** and the second term is the classical **kinetic energy**. Now, what this has to do with the weak, strong forces and general relativity? Well, not much, except that special relativity (the physical theory which introduced this concept) is presupposed by all other modern physical theories which followed (since 1905) the relativistic mass is naturally included in those theories. However, $m_o$ is more basic in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

For more information about the question, you can look at this interview of Boyd Bushman, former Lockheed Martin Skunk works senior scientist(timemark 16:00): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hNPBYtJyfZo

Comment: Fascinating, that must have been the original source of their having told me that. This was at a Tesla coil builders conf and I haven't gotten back in touch with them yet. Thanks for what appears to be their original source.